# Proof writing: Euler's theorem.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

> Let $a$ and $n$ be integers such that $n >0$ and $gcd(a,n)=1$. Then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1$ (mod $n$). (with $\phi(n)$ being the Euler function)

**Proof:**

Since $|U(n)|=\phi(n)$ and $a\in U(n)$ because $gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}=a^{|U(n)|}=1$ for all $a\in U(n)$. Then $n|(a^{\phi(n)}-1)$. Then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1$ (mod $n$).

> This was the proof given in class, and we did not discuss any Euler quotient. So how do I deduce that $n|(a^{\phi(n)}-1)$? I cannot find the connection.

Comment: What is $U(n)$?

Comment: If $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \mod n$.  Then $a^{\phi(n)} - 1 \equiv 0 \mod n$.  So $n|a^{\phi(n)} - 1$. But, um,  .... yeah,  what is $U(n)$?  The group of $\langle a^n, \times \mod n\rangle$?

Comment: Sorry! $U(n)$ is the group of units, where $U(n)=$ set of integers $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ such that $gcd(a,n)=1$.

Comment: And you have proved that that is a group?  Under modulo multiplication?  Then the result follows as $a^{|U(n)|} \equiv 1 \mod n$.  That means $a^{|U(n)|} - 1 \equiv 0 \mod n$.  So $a^{\phi(n)} - 1 \equiv 0 \mod n$.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you, this is a very clear answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That proof seems straight forward to me.

Let $U(n)$ be the set of units modulo $n$ that is $U(n)=\{k \in Z_{n}| \gcd(k,n) = 1\}$.

$|U(n)| = \phi(n)$, of course.

And under multiplication $U(n)$ is a group.

Pf: $1 \in U(n)$ and $1*k = k$.  If $k \in U(n)$ then by Bezout, there are $p, q$ so that $pk + mn = 1$ and thus  $pk \equiv 1 \mod n$ and as an equivalency class $p$ is the inverse of $k$.  And $p$ must be relatively prime to $n$ or else $pk + mn$ could not be $1$.  So every element of $U(n)$ has an inverse. QED.

Using the notation of $[m]$ to be the equivalence class of the integer $m$ we get:  $|U(n)| = \phi(n)$.  Then for any $[a] \in U(n)$, by Legrange's Theorem,  we have $[a]^{|U(n)|} = [a]^{\phi(n)}=[a^{\phi(n)}]=[1]$ under the group operation.

But the group operation is nothing more than multiplication of equivalency classes.  So $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$. and that's that.

The proof took an extra step that for $[a], [b] \in U(n)$ to say that $[a] = [b]$ means that $n| (b- a)$.  I don't see that that step makes things any easier of clearer.  In fact I think it muddies things.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to respond. I understand what you mean. I have another question: in the part of the proof I provided where it says "Since $|U(n)|=\phi(n)$ and $a\in U(n)$ because $gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}=a^{|U(n)|}=1$ for all $a\in U(n)$," is this because $a$ generates $U(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, for every natural number $n$, the value $\phi(n)$ the Euler $\phi$ function at $n$ is defined as the number of elements in the set $\{ 1, \dots, n \}$ that are relatively prime to $n$; that is, 
$$ \phi(n) = \# \{ \ x \in \mathbb{N}: \ x \leq n, \ \mathrm{gcd}(x, n) = 1 \ \} = \left\lvert  \{ \ x \in \mathbb{N}: \ x \leq n, \ \mathrm{gcd}(x, n) = 1 \ \} \right\rvert,$$
where, for any set $S$, $\#(S)$ or $\lvert S \rvert$ denotes the cardinality of $S$, which of course is the same as the number of elements in $S$ if $S$ is a finite set.

Now suppose that $a$ and $n$ are integers such that $n > 0$ and $\mathrm{gcd} (a, n) = 1$. Let $r_1, \ldots, r_{\phi(n)}$ be the natural numbers in the set $\{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ that are relatively prime to $n$. Then, for each $i = 1, \ldots, \phi(n)$, we can write
$$ r_i x_i + n y_i = 1$$
for a unique pair of integers $x_i$ and $y_i$, and so 
$$ r_i x_i - 1 = n y_i, \tag{1}$$
which implies that 
$$ r_i x_i \equiv 1 \  (\mod n), \tag{2}$$
and (1) also implies that $\mathrm{gcd} \left( x_i, n \right) = 1$ also, and so 
$$ \mathrm{gcd} \left( r_i x_i, n \right) = 1. \tag{3} $$
Hope these facts are clear to you.

Now (2) gives 
$$ a r_i x_i \equiv a\  ( \mod n). \tag{4}$$
for each $i = 1, \ldots, \phi(n)$.

Multiplying together all the congruences in (4) we obtain
$$ a^{\phi(n)} \prod_{i=1}^{\phi(n)} r_i x_i \equiv a^{\phi(n)}\  ( \mod n). \tag{5} $$
But from (3) we can also conclude that 
$$ \mathrm{gcd} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{\phi(n)} r_i x_i \ , \ n \right) = \prod_{i=1}^{\phi(n)} r_i x_i \mathrm{gcd} \left( r_i x_i \ , \ n \right) = 1. \tag{6} $$
Now by virtue of (6), we can divide both sides of (5) by the non-zero integer $\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(n)} r_i x_i $ to obtain 
$$ a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \ ( \mod n), $$
as required.

Hope this is helpful.